# Best practice for using two backgrounds

Tags: css

I have a site where I use a background image as the "lower" background, then I have a transparent white background colour underneath the content of the website. This is how I have it coded now:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="inner">
  <p>content</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
 background-image: url(img/bg.png);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.inner {
 width: 40%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 100px 7.5% 0 7.5%;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
}
```

This is so to achieve a full background image with the content centred and having a white background underneath it, with an opacity layer to it.

I have to use padding on the top of the `.inner` (of 100px) to create more space above all the content. If I use to let us say a margin instead, then the white background image gets removed from the area above and the background image of the `.wrapper` appears instead. And doing it with a `<br>` isn't really good. So my question is this is this a good practice to do all of this or should I take another approach to:

1. Having a background image and a background colour?
2. Achieving the space inside the `.inner` with the padding?

Comment: You will still need a `inner` for centering your content (wrapper `display: flex;` and inner `margin: auto;`), but you can combine the background with a background-color simply by setting `background-color` or using the shorthand. It can even ba a transparent color. You could also define multiple `background-image` values separated by a comma.

Comment: If you want space at the top of inner then use padding - that's what it's for

Comment: Ah okay thanks guys, will change it up!